# Write this HTML from this JSON result (parsing JSON)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this JSON result:

```
{
    "html_content": [
        [
            [
                "Navegantes",
                "11",
                "8",
                "3",
                "0"
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                "Tigres",
                "11",
                "8",
                "3",
                "0"
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                "Caribes",
                "11",
                "6",
                "5",
                "2"
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                "Leones",
                "11",
                "6",
                "5",
                "2"
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                "Aguilas",
                "11",
                "5",
                "6",
                "3"
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                "Tiburones",
                "10",
                "4",
                "6",
                "3.5"
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                "Cardenales",
                "10",
                "3",
                "7",
                "4.5"
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                "Bravos",
                "11",
                "3",
                "8",
                "5"
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

And I need to build, for each a HTML markup like this one:

```
<tr>
    <td>Navegantes</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Tigres</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And so on, I made  this code:

```
$.each(data.html_content, function(i, v) {
    htm += "here goes the HTML code";
});
```

But this doesn't work I think due to array kind, can any help?

Comment: you need to serialize the json to object and use the object to create html

Comment: good time to look into knockoutjs or angularjs.

Comment: Why does every sub-array have its own sub-array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.html_content.length; i++) {
   var tr = "<tr>";
   var td = "";
   for (var j = 0; j < data.html_content[i][0].length; j++) {
       td += "<td>" + data.html_content[i][0][j] + "</td>"; 
   }
   tr += td + "<td><span></span><span></span></td></tr>";
   $("table").append(tr);
}
```

Comment: Finally I got yours but you have a error since `var tr = "<tr>";` should be initialize outside the first `for`cycle but the rest works fine

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this ([**AN EXAMPLE.**](http://jsfiddle.net/VFFf4/1/))

```
var table = $('<table/>')
$.each(data.html_content, function(k, v){
    var tr = $('<tr/>');
    $.each(v[0], function(i, j){
        $('<td/>', { 'text':j }).appendTo(tr);
    });
    var sp1 = $('<span/>', { 'class':'glyphicon glyphicon-play', 'text':'Play' });
    var sp2 = $('<span/>', { 'class':'glyphicon glyphicon-stop', 'text':'Stop' });
    var tdSpan = $('<td/>');
    tdSpan.append(sp1).append(sp2);
    tr.append(tdSpan);
    table.append(tr);
});
$('body').append(table);
```

Comment: This solution works but I need to remove `<table>` tags since I only need `<tr>` tags, what code should I remove in order to get only them?

Answer (score 0):

You can write this from scratch, but there are plenty of [JS templating scripts available](http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/) that can consume JSON.

See: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/12/05/client-side-templating/ on how they work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic solution fron scratch :

```
$.each(data.html_content, function(i, v) {
    htm += '<tr>' +
        '    <td>' + i[0][0] + '</td>' +
        '    <td>' + i[0][1] + '</td>' +
        '    <td>' + i[0][2] + '</td>' +
        '    <td>' + i[0][3] + '</td>' +
        '    <td>' + i[0][4] + '</td>' +
        '    <td>' +
        '        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>' +
        '        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></span>' +
        '    </td>' +
        '</tr>';
});
```